# Taylor 510e Acoustic/Electric guitar won't stay in tune

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar

I picked this guitar out because it wasn't a low end or cheap guitar. I wanted something with a little quality and the Martin's were just a bit out of 
my price range. I put brand new strings on it and ever since day one, I can rarely
get through one song and have to re-tune. It seems to almost always be the 'G' and/or 'B' and sometimes 'E' strings that always go out of tune.
I'm using strings made for acoustic guitars. 
Thanks,

Mat

Comment: How long have you had the guitar? How long ago did you replace the strings? Very new strings will need to be tuned several times before they hold the notes...

Comment: New strings will get out of tune regularly for around a week. If you just changed them, don't worry about it.

Comment: Also make sure you know how to properly wind the strings. If you are not putting them on correctly they will slip.

Comment: Hope I'm doing this right, using the comment to reply. I have owned the Taylor for about a year. I put the strings on right away as I always do when I buy a new axe.

Comment: Hope I'm doing this right, using the comment to reply. I have owned the Taylor for about a year. I put the strings on right away as I always do when I buy a new axe. So they've been on there long enough. And being that I own around 28 or so guitars and basses, I'm sure by now I know how to string a guitar. But, I want to thank all you guys for your responses. I filled out my profile a little more so people can get a better understanding who I am. The reason I put anything on here at all is because believe there are some knowledgeable people on here and might point me in the right direction.

Comment: So you put new strings as soon as you bought the guitar, and haven't tested with other set of strings? The strings might be the issue, then.

Comment: So, it's a relatively new guitar, you know how to re-string. Why hasn't it gone straight back to the seller?

Comment: @Lyd - put on properly, new strings (on my guitars) need a day at most (usually after I've done the job!) before tuning stability is established.

Comment: The dealer claimed it was used for approximately 5 mos and then traded in. And I traded an old electric guitar in on it so, there's noway to take it back. I admit, I haven't tried another brand of strings yet. I've found most acoustic strings to be close to the same, in the same gauge of course with subtle differences. And I don't believe that would be the cause of this issue at this time. However, 'today, as a matter of fact,' making my way to the music store and picking up another set of strings and tryin that out regardless of my opinion, I'm needing new sets for my PRS and 69 SG anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try these in this order

1. Put new strings on and stretch them thoroughly as you tune. Play the guitar for a couple hours and re-stretch/retune a few times. Notice if a string gets caught on the nut or bridge saddle as you tune. If so, have these fixed/replaced so there's less friction. There are also products to lubricate the nut if it's very minor.
2. Notice if you can tug on a string and see it slip on the tuning peg. It's easier to see with wound strings. And see if the peg rotates just by tugging on the string. For the former, the issue is how you are stringing. For the latter, it's the tuners (though less likely since this happens on multiple strings).
3. GENTLY apply push and pull to the headstock while the body is anchored. Just use a finger or two. If the pitch of the strings changes with a delicate push or pull, the guitar is unstable. The truss rod may be too loose, broken, the neck may have an invisible crack, the neck joint may be unstable, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. I will do and report back. Thanks

Comment: @MainMatK. please mark this is the correct answer if you think it answered your question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your truss rod is turned to tightly to the right, creating an inward bow so great, your guitar is relying on your string tension alone for stability. Strings will constantly slip this way. Turn your truss rod counterclockwise till u see the concave straighten. Also w every adjustment,  hit the open string, tune it then on the same string,  tune again at the strings 2nd octave somewhere between 10 and 12th frets. Your guitar should stay it's tune when pressing on the fret and while it's open

Comment: Tune this way on all 6 strings every single time u make an adjustment. If string is in tune while open but out of tune on the octave,  keep adjusting rod till u achieve all tuned octaves